# What is meant by corollary of the Hahn-Banach theorem "Linear functionals detect norms"

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

I came accross these descriptions for the corollaries of the Hahn-Banach theorem. I am wondering what is meant by the description "Linear functionals detect norms". Why is it significant that there exists a linear functional which maps a single element to its norm? Couldn't I construct a linear functional which makes $L(x)$ take on any arbitrary value? Why does this particular property help us?

> Corollary 21.10. Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a normed vector space.
>
> (i) If $\mathcal{M} \subset \mathcal{X}$ is a subspace and $L: \mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ is a bounded linear functional, then there exists a bounded linear functional $L^{\prime}: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ such that $\left.L^{\prime}\right|_{\mathscr{M}}=L$ and $\left\|L^{\prime}\right\|=\|L\|$.
>
> (ii) (Linear functionals detect norms) If $x \in \mathcal{X}$ is nonzero, there exists $L \in \mathcal{X}^{*}$ with $\|L\|=1$ such that $L(x)=\|x\|$.
>
> (iii) (Linear functionals separate points) If $x \neq y$ in $\mathcal{X}$, there exists $L \in \mathcal{X}^{*}$ such that $L(x) \neq L(y)$.

Comment: Suppose you know Riesz's theorem, then 2. is sort of 'expectable'. I myself haven't done the particular theorem you've mentioned tho

Comment: @Buraian Can this be thought of as\ the dual space doesn't forget what the norms of the points in $X$ are? There is always a linear functional that maps x to its norm?

Comment: As I said before, I am not familiar with this particular theorem, but I think I agree. I guess the point is that whatever inner product we choose (and hence norm), given a vector, there is some linear functional in the dual space such that the specific vector mentioned before is mapped to it's norm under the norm originally chosen. I don't get why it's saying that it's being 'detected' though.. is there some aspect of the norm being hidden?

Comment: If you want $\|L\|$ to be $1$ then $L(x)$ cannot be arbitrary. $\|Lx\| \leq (1)( \|x\|)$ and (ii) says that you can actually make this an equality.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy What is also significant about $\|L\|$ being 1?